# The iterator() method in the following class needs help please

Tags: java

So the very first method iterator() calls the constructor of AIterator class which resets the index to 0 every time the constructor is called. And so each time I try to iterate through a collection using iterator().hasNext() and iteratro().next() it turns into an infinite loop. Not sure how to deal with this. Can you please help? I have pasted AIterator class at the bottom too. They are in the same package.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException;

/**
 * Comment me!!!
 * @author 
 * @version 
 */

    // equals method needs work probably
    // Works till add()
    // Enters into infinite loop when trying to run addAll()
    // Everything in between /* ... */ and // and /** .... **/ are experiments or thought :)


public class Aset<R> implements Set151Interface<R>{
    // TODO: write code

    public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    private R[] genArray;



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Aset(int size) {
        if(size < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        genArray = (R[]) new Object[size];
    }

    public Aset() {
        this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Aset(Collection<? extends R> collection) {
        this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
        if (collection == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        genArray = (R[]) collection.toArray();
        //addAll(collection);
        /*
        Iterator<R> myIterator = this.iterator();
        while(myIterator.hasNext()) {
            R current = myIterator.next();
            if(current == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            if(!(this.contains(current))) {
                this.add(current);
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        }

        */

    }

    /**
     * Provides a method for traversing an array using a well-known Java interface.
     * @return an interator that can traverse the given ADT.
     **/
    @Override
    public Iterator<R> iterator() {

        Iterator<R> aSetIterator = new AIterator<R>(genArray, size());
        //AIterator<R> aSetIterator = this.iterator();
        return aSetIterator;

    }





    @Override
    public boolean add(R q) {
        if(q == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        /*
        while(iterator().hasNext()) {
            if(this.equals(q)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        */      
        checkCapacity();
        genArray[size()] = q;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        while(iterator().hasNext()) {
            remove(iterator().next());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return genArray.length == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends R> c) {
        int check = size();
        if(checkType(c)) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Aset<R> newCollection = (Aset<R>) c;
            System.out.println(newCollection.size());
            while(newCollection.iterator().hasNext()) {
                    add(newCollection.iterator().next());
                    newCollection.iterator().next();
            }

        }
        /*
        R currentCollection = c.iterator().next();
        while(iterator().hasNext()) {
            while(c.iterator().hasNext()) {
                if(!this.contains(currentCollection)) {
                    add(currentCollection); // or change iterator().next() with "this"
                }
            }
        }
        */
        if(check == size()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int aSetSize = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < genArray.length; i++) {
            if(genArray[i] != null) {
                aSetSize++;
            }
        }
        return aSetSize;
        /*int aSetSize = 0;
            while(iterator().hasNext()) {
                if(iterator().next() != null) {
                    aSetSize++;
                }
            }
        return aSetSize;
        */
    }

    public int getCapacity() {

        if(genArray.length <= DEFAULT_CAPACITY){
            return DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
        }
        return genArray.length;
    }

    private void checkCapacity() {
        if(size() >= genArray.length) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            R[] newGenArray = (R[]) new Object[genArray.length + DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
            System.arraycopy(genArray, 0, newGenArray, 0, size());
            genArray = newGenArray;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] array){

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(genArray);
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Aset)) {
            return false;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Aset<R> other = (Aset<R>) obj;
        if (!(size() == other.size()) && compareArrays(genArray, other.genArray)) {
            System.out.println("2 :( ");
            System.out.println(genArray.length);
            System.out.println(other.genArray.length);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // probably needs to be sorted before using this method
    private boolean compareArrays(R a[], R b[]) {
        Arrays.sort(a);
        Arrays.sort(b);
        int shortArrLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        for (int i = 0; i<shortArrLength; i++) {
            if(!(a[i].hashCode() == b[i].hashCode())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<" + Arrays.toString(genArray) + ">";
    }
    */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (size() == 0) {
            return "<>";
        }
        String aSet = "";
        for(R element:genArray) {
            if(element != null) {
                aSet += ", " + element.toString();
            }
        }
        return "<" + aSet.substring(2) + ">";
    }

    private boolean checkType(Object other) {

        if(other.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**AIterator class**
I have made changes to next() because I thought index was not increasing anywhere in the class and it probably would result in infinite loop too If I haven't added index++ before the return statement.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
/**
 * This class creates an iterator to travers an Aset object.
 * @author William Kreahling
 * @version 10/1/2014
 */
public class AIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{
    private int index;
    private E[] data;
    private int size;

    /**
     * Created an iterator for an Aset Object.
     * @param data the generic array for Aset.
     * @param size the number of elements (cardinality) of the set.
     */
    public AIterator(E[] data, int size) {
        index = 0;
        this.size = size;
        this.data = data;

    }
    /**
     * Returns the next element of the collection.
     * @return the next element if the set.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if there are no elements left in the set.
     */
    public E next() {
        if (index >= size) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot access element " + index +
                                             "This set has a total of " + size + " elements.");
        }
        index++;                        // this line has been added
        return data[index];             // this line has been edited from -> return data[index++];
    }

    /**
     * Determines if there are elements left in the set.
     * @return true if there are more elements in the set.
     */
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index >= 0 && index < size;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("AIterator does not support remove");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as below.

```
Iterator<XX> it = theASet.iterator();
//in loop 
it.next();
```

Don't use `theASet.iterator()` and `theASet.next()` because it will make a new instance of iterator and its index is always zero.

Comment: here as the iterator() is being called on the class, it needs to be static I believe. But the problem is it is an instance method.

Comment: Iterator<R> it = (AIterator<R>) this.iterator();
//in loop 
it.next();